# There is currently a flood in the Reopen Votes review queue

Tags: support, review, reopen

> Related: [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196074/184688) at meta.stackoverflow.

The review queue for reopen votes is currently at an exceptional high. Did something happen system-side to bring this on? A lot of the posts currently in that queue are minor edits, sometimes from quite a while ago (such as [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22801), which was edited July 17). Normally this should not come up on the review queue (or at least not now). What is going on?

I'll try and do my 20 reviews' worth today, but this thing needs at least six people-days of flat-out reviews.

Comment: @Manishearth Shog9's answer in MSO indicates that we might get a new batch of 50 questions tomorrow. Unless they confirm we've got the whole set, it's probably prudent to hold that tag for the time being.

Comment: Hmm, good point, will do.

Comment: I saw the flood. If only I could click.

Comment: @Manishearth Here we go again, back to 70. I'll do a few and save some votes for nontrivial ones. It would be good if we could ping Shog9 to get an estimate of how long this will take, though.

Comment: (I don't even know if I can do it my self. @Shog9, does this reach you?)

Comment: Hmmm. I swear a lot of these came up yesterday. [This one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22928) definitely did, [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22803).

Comment: It's come up thrice. This is strange.

Comment: Yes, there's a bunch of dupes. [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22930) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22797). [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22805) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22938). [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22817) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22950). Most of what I saw today was there yesterday. (See the full list [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/8563/emilio-pisanty?tab=activity&sort=reviews) and in page 3.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm finding them too. (I can get to the review page of a given question, and here I see two or three links per question). This is a bug. The devs have been pinged.

Comment: @Manishearth OK, cool. Ping me here if there's something I can do.

Comment: Haha, that's the best rollback reason I've ever seen.

Answer (score 4):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078):

> Currently, this means that a closed question will automatically be
>   added to the reopen queue when it is...
>
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by the author. Or,
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to
>     delete it. Or,
> - ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month. We're still
>     tweaking the exact thresholds for these, but right now they're fairly
>     generous - however, the most popular closed questions are being added
>     to the queue *first*.

---

This is probably an initial flood of questions, once we clear it out the queue ought to stay empty (like how all the queues were above 100 when they were introduced). There are edits from July there, so they probably allowed the algorithm to retroactively apply itself.

> but this thing needs at least six people-days of flat-out reviews.

Not if I can do anything about it :P

Comment: Re: _Not if I can do anything about it_ - yeah, a lot of those posts are there through moderatorial actions. If this is a system change that needs a one-time community response then we should all pull our weight (after all, most of the votes are easy to decide) but mods can do more about this about this than regular users. One thing to watch out for is questions getting buried there.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Exactly. Most of those are minor edits that can just be plowed through. The ones that are not -- well, I'm skipping them now and making a note of them in chat to come to later.